# What is the name of this symbol?

Tags: symbols

What is the name of this symbol and how I can write it using Latex?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to tex,sx.  Where did you find it, and what is the context?

Comment: http://shapecatcher.com/unicode/info/4276?

Comment: It is very much like the “phar” (or p’ari) letter in the Georgian script Asomtavruli (don't pronounce it “far”, but with an aspirated “p”). The picture, however, seems more like two P stuck together, after reflection of one of them.

Comment: Thank you all for your reply. I found this symbol in a compuer science paper. The authors of the paper use it to denote a Performance Portability metric.

Answer (score 4):

To me this looks exactly like a mirrored P merged with a normal P. I couldn't find it with Detexify, but it's not hard to construct.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newlength{\fslength}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\funnyP}{%
    \setlength{\fslength}{\f@size pt}%
    \reflectbox{P}\hspace*{-.359\fslength}\mbox{P}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\( \funnyP \) 
{\small \funnyP} 
{\funnyP} 
{\Large \funnyP} 
{\Huge \funnyP}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

That symbol is [qp ligature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qp_ligature) that is a combination of q and p (or c and p, or mirrored p and p). Perhaps here the symbol is in uppercase form. The Unicode of this symbol (in lowercase form) is U+0239 which can be used in tex engines other than pdflatex.

Here's another solution for using in normal latex which make use of `\reflectbox` to mirror P letter like this

[image]

A command like `\qpligature` can be defined as in the code below and used in either text or math mode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}
%
\newcommand{\qpligature}{\ensuremath{\reflectbox{\text{P}}\mkern-6mu\text{P}}}
%
\begin{document}
%

%
\section{Text mode}
In text mode with different size:

\qpligature  \quad \large \qpligature \quad \Large \qpligature \quad \huge \qpligature
%

\normalsize

\section{Math mode}

In inline equations $ \qpligature = q p $

In separate equations:

%
\begin{align*}
    \qpligature = q p
\end{align*}
%

\huge
%
\begin{align*}
\qpligature = q p
\end{align*}
%

\end{document}
```

Comment: The "qp ligature" is by (Unicode) definition a "small letter", whereas the letter shown in the question is distinctly uppercase.  Two different things.

Comment: Then it's an upper case qp ligature. Same concept applies!

Comment: I just thought to dig into the origin of that symbol and where it came from.

Comment: @barbara beeton Well I explained that in an edit for the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, an uppercase "QP ligature" wouldn't look like this, because an uppercase "Q" is round with a tail.  Historically in the Latin alphabet, lowercase forms weren't developed until much later than the uppercase forms, which were the forms inscribed on stone columns.  So it's possible in some other script (Georgian has been suggested and rejected), but not Latin/italic.  I'm still hoping that the OP will provide more information.

Comment: So what do you suggest name this symbol?

Comment: I won't attempt to name it without ore information about its context.  If it has been used in a math paper, the author will have defined it, and that gives a possible hook.  A symbol I encountered a few years ago is a mirrored "L"; it has since been used in multiple math works by different authors.  The name by which these authors refer to it is "Le", referential to the shape but not the meaning.  If this *is* math, it likely has a history, but I don't know it.  I know it's not a phonetic/lingustic representation.

Comment: Thank you all for your reply. I found this symbol in a compuer science paper. The authors of the paper use it to denote a Performance Portability metric.